# Passing a variable to a child class from a super class through a void method

Tags: java, inheritance

so i want to pass s to a child class that over writes this class and use s in the childs method as i wish to print a message from the child class depending on the number s is

t is a private array and nt is a private number, is it possible to do so

```
void c() {
      int s= 0;

      for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i++){
         s+= t[i];
      }
      s= s/nt;

    }
```

Comment: There is nothing called "overriding classes". You can only inherit (extend) from classes. Are you aware of the access specifier [protected](https://www.baeldung.com/java-protected-access-modifier)?

Comment: In clear code you can't access private variable (see protected). But there is a way to access private variable via reflection (but commonly it is bad practice, i does not know one case where it is need). As say @Stan, you can also use methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the method return the value?

I would do something like this:

```
//parent class method
int c() {
  int s= 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i++){
     s+= t[i];
  }
  s= s/nt;
  return s;
}

//child class method
void printDependingOnNumber() {
  if(super.c()==0 /*or whatever number*/){
     //print here   
  }
}
```

To me it seems that the method "c" only calculates the value of "s", so making it a void isn't very convenient. Making it return int allows you to calculate that value in the child class too.

Comment: I agree with you buddy, but we were given directions for it to be a void

Comment: Would it be ok to make "s" a private property (or save it's final value to one)? This sort of stuff should be fixed by modelling it better, as it is right now, the method "c" it's useless.